# using jq to update a json value

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "cmp": {
    "vr1": {
      "vr2": {
        "mpa": [
          "foo1",
          "foo2"          
        ]
      }
    }
  },  
  "at": "",
  "pl": {
    "accountId": ""
  },
  "sv": {
    "accountId": ""
  }
}
```

I am trying to use `jq` to replace the values in the JSON array `mpa` from ["foo1", "foo2"] to ["bar1", "bar2"]. How can I do this?

My attempt:

```
jq -r -e \
    .[].cmp.vr1.vr2.mpa=["bar1", "bar2"]
    < /tmp/json-file.json
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`.[]` are [Array/Object Value **Iterator's**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D).

Since you're dealing with an object, no need to use an iterator, you can target your array like so:

```
jq '.cmp.vr1.vr2.mpa = [ "bar1", "bar2" ]' input.json
```

[Snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/Ioj8q0uag8)